# Alfresco or Liferay, which is better for WCM?

Tags: content-management-system, liferay, alfresco, wcm

I am exploring CMS tools Alfresco and Liferay, but cant decide which is better for Web Content Management.
Please help me decide which tool to use for web. Opinions and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Just use your favourite search machine and voila I've got topics covering this question:

e.g. [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8612157)

Comment: thanks Tahir. The discussion forum content helped me a lot.

Comment: No Problem :), good that it has sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't decide, go for the pragmatic solution and just pick one.

You'll have to decide if you rather like the Content- or the Portal-centric approach - e.g. what else other than CMS do you expect from the solution you choose. As you ask for opinions: I'm tending to prefer a portal (but then, I'll have to disclaim that I work for Liferay) because it can integrate quite a lot more functionality - and extension is done through a well known standard interface (portlets). And I'm typically seeing requirements that ask for more than just content management.

Integration of both products is possible, but it's an additional effort that needs to be done - and you'll have to understand both. There are many people doing that, but if one solution goes 95% of what you need, you could save yourself the integration work.

But if you really want some useful answers here you might want to give more information about what you actually want to use them for, because personal opinions and suggestions might not help you with your personal requirements if you leave them unknown.

Comment: Thanks Olak. I am working on liferay now .I am finding it more appropriate to my requirement as it is a Dynamic website .

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/09/liferay-train-of-thoughts.html) should be helpful enough as to WCM in Liferay. Talking about WCM (not Document/Enterprise content management) I would go with Liferay, because it is really easy and quite powerful, especially recently after a few new features were introduced (very cool web content staging and versioning). Alfresco is good for enterprise content management, but I wouldn't choose it for WCM, the Spring Surf and Spring Web Scripts it is using was quite hard to get used to.